# Incrementing Cassandra Counter Column Family in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am trying to do an insert/increment in cassandra database through node.js...

Suppose I have this table:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY MsCounter
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND default_validation_class = CounterColumnType;
```

then let's say i want to insert/increment a row key and a value on MsCounter:

```
rowKey: 'Tim', columnName1: columnName1 + 1
```

Is there any way to do this programatically in Node Js using 
[cassandra-client](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client) ?

I am aware they show an example of inserting and updating a regular column family, but does the same applied for counter column family ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this [sample](https://gist.github.com/gdusbabek/2369391) , I realize that it is possible to do the CQL without using the optional parameter. Here is how I do it in my case:

```
con.execute('UPDATE MsCounter SET columnName = columnName + 1 WHERE key=?', ['Tim'], function(err) {});
```